# When creating an XSD what is the correct syntax for simpleType?

Tags: xml, xsd

Is this a correct syntax or do I need to change the first simple type to complex?

```
<xs:simpleType name="t_name">
       <xs:attribute name="a_name" >
          <xs:simpleType>
             <xs:restriction base="xs:hexBinary" >
                <xs:length value="4”/>
             </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
       </xs:attribute>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this should be a Complex type

provided that xs is defined as  `<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`

From the W3Schools article "[What is a Complex Element?](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex.asp)"

> A complex element is an XML element that contains other elements
>   and/or attributes.
>
> There are four kinds of complex elements:
>
> - empty elements
> - elements that contain only other elements
> - elements that contain only text
> - elements that contain both other elements and text Note: Each of
>     these elements may contain attributes as well!

So because of the attribute  `<xs:attribute name="a_name" >` you need to make it a complex type

If you save the following as a file and validated it [here](http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:simpleType name="t_name">
       <xs:attribute name="a_name" >
          <xs:simpleType>
             <xs:restriction base="xs:hexBinary" >
                <xs:length value="4"/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
     </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

You would get the following

> Invalid per cvc-complex-type.1.2.4: element
>   {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}
>   **:attribute not allowed here (1) in element
>   {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}:simpleType,**  expecting
>   [{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}:annotation,{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}:restriction,{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}:list,{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}:union]: